# php code to insert series of strings into database

Tags: php, arrays, database, string

I have one string, it is given below,

```
$str = '1, test1, 22, 2, test2, 44, 3, test4, 55, 4, test7, 12...';
```

The string contains `id, name, age`, I have to insert into database like this,

```
 id | name | age  
  1 | test1| 22    
  2 | test2| 44
```

Please let me know, How can I achieve this one?

Thanks In advance

Comment: What you gave is a string..

Comment: @Ugly Eddie...it is string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can just build a multi insert query on this one. Consider this example:

```
$str = '1, test1, 22, 2, test2, 44, 3, test4, 55, 4, test7, 12';
$str = explode(',', $str);
$str = array_map('trim', $str);
$data = array_chunk($str, 3);
$values = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $values[] = '("'.implode('", "', $value).'")';
}
$statement = "INSERT INTO `table` (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ". implode(',', $values);

// this produces:
// INSERT INTO `table` (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ("1", "test1", "22"),("2", "test2", "44"),("3", "test4", "55"),("4", "test7", "12")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like....

```
$str = '1, test1, 22, 2, test2, 44, 3, test4, 55, 4, test7, 12';  
$array = explode(", ",$str);
$result_array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

I guess you can take ahead from this to insert that into your db.

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/J7JBvt)**.

Comment: @Rikesh..this will work..but if the string length is 100000, then we have to write too many queries for this..Is there any other method, so that we can insert it in one query?

Comment: You can create a single query too.

Comment: @Rikesh..How can I acheive this one?..can you give any demo??